# Using a boolean attribute in an Angular Dart Component

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I have a component that I would like to use in this way:

```
<my-component text='ctrl.text' editable></my-component>
```

`editable` is boolean and following correct HTML semantics, does not need a value. If the `editable` attribute is included, it maps to an empty string, and if it isn't, processing it returns a null.

What is the correct and idiomatic way to use this boolean in my component code?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for [Port of ng-attr-foo from angular-js](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/382/commits).
It's not yet in the master branch and therefor also not in the current release (0.9.4)

The example in the DartDoc comment of [ng_attribute.dart](https://github.com/nerdrew/angular.dart/blob/08097bd465665388cd520fb0cfd119a751d84b17/lib/directive/ng_attribute.dart) shows how to use it.

Comment: This use case is not yet supported well.